# Highcharts tooltip overflow is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, highcharts

My problem is that when the chart drawing area of is smaller than a highchart tooltip, a part of the tooltip is hidden where it overflows the chart drawing area.

I want the tooltip to be visible all the time, no matter the size of the chart drawing area.

No CSS setting helped and no higher z-index setting helped either.

Here is my example... http://twitpic.com/9omgg5

Any help will be mostly apreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why isn't this question marked as 'answered'? Almost every answer is the right one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, sorry for the delay. I could not find a better solution, but I found a workaround.

Here is what I did and what I suggest everyone to try:

**Set the tooltip.useHTML property to true** (now you can have more control with html and CSS). Like this:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true    
}
```

**Unset all the default tooltip peoperties** that may have something to do with the default tooltip functionalities. Here is what I did...

```
tooltip: {                        
    shared: false,
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    enabled: true,
    backgroundColor: 'none'
}
```

**Make sure that your chart container's css property "overflow" is set to visible.** Also make sure that all DOM elements (div, section, etc....) that hold your chart container also have the css "overflow" property set to "visible". In this way you will make sure that your tooltip will be visibile at all times as it overflows his parent and his other "ancestors" (Is this a correct term? :)).

**Customize your tooltip formatter as you wish, using standard CSS styling.** Here is what I did:

```
tooltip.formatter: {
    < div class ="tooltipContainer"> Tooltip content here < /div >
}
```

---

This is how it all looks like:

```
tooltip: {                        
    tooltip.formatter: {
        < div class ="tooltipContainer"> Tooltip content here < /div >
    },
    useHTML: true,
    shared: false,
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    enabled: true,
    backgroundColor: 'none'
}
```

If you have a better solution, please post.

Comment: Should be the best answer, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 25):

This css helped me:

```
.highcharts-container { overflow: visible !important; }
```

Comment: you would have to add, that you have to set `tooltip: { useHTML: true }`, too

Comment: Not working for me, only setting svg css property to visible worked

Comment: Both .highcharts-container { overflow: visible !important; } and svg {
                overflow: visible;
            } are needed.

Answer (score 12):

A modern approach (Highcharts 6.1.1 and newer) is to simply use `tooltip.outside` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside)):

> Whether to allow the tooltip to render outside the chart's SVG element box. By default (`false`), the tooltip is rendered within the chart's SVG element, which results in the tooltip being aligned inside the chart area. For small charts, this may result in clipping or overlapping. When `true`, a separate SVG element is created and overlaid on the page, allowing the tooltip to be aligned inside the page itself.

Quite simply this means setting this one value to `true`, for example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    // Your options...
    tooltip: {
        outside: true
    }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/71uknto5/6/) of how setting this value to `true` fixes space/clipping issues.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and should be the actual answer to the original question.

Comment: After trying so many options, this is the one that solved my problem thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Andy I agree that this is the best answer however when the question was asked the newest version of Highcharts was something like 2.2

Answer (score 5):

Adding simply this CSS worked in my case (minicharts in table cells):

```
.highcharts-container svg {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

The tooltip option useHtml was not required:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: false
}
```

Works on both IE8/9 & FF33.1 (FF was causing trouble).

Answer (score 5):

I recently got the same problem, but with bootstrap container ! (bs3)

None of those solutions worked but I found by my own.

Its due to bootstrap _normalizer properties

```
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

So add both :

```
.highcharts-container, svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I shall try this.It seems to me highcharts should fix this

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old but I just wanted to share my solution, it's based on the other two answers but I think that you obtain a better-looking result with this code:

**Tooltip options:**

```
tooltip: {
   useHTML: true,
   shared: false,
   borderRadius: 0,
   borderWidth: 0,
   shadow: false,
   enabled: true,
   backgroundColor: 'none',
   formatter: function() {
      return '<span style="border-color:'+this.point.color+'">' + this.point.name + '</span>';
   }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.highcharts-container { 
    overflow: visible !important; 
}

.highcharts-tooltip span>span {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    border:1px solid;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#divContainerId .highcharts-container{
    z-index: 10 !important; /*If you have problems with the label hiding behind some other div or chart play with z-index*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me. When the tooltip was bigger than the chart it simply didn't show.

Eventually we realized that Highcharts actually hides the tooltip in the class `highcharts-tooltip-box`, so the solution is to set it to inherit which the class default:

```
 .highcharts-tooltip-box {
    visibility: inherit !important;
  }
```

After that overflow still need to be set to visible:

```
  .highcharts-container,
  svg:not(:root),
  .chart-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
```

And make sure to set the z-index higher in the container if you're having any problems.

Comment: Thank you this is absolutely the answer that solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add an example and prove that .highcharts-tooltip-box
doesn't have to be set for overflow to work.

```
/* .highcharts-tooltip-box {
  visibility: inherit !important;
} */

.highcharts-container,
svg:not(:root),
.chart-container {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3fubr1av/