# Whitespace in IE10 on Windows 8 when highcharts-container overflow is visible

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the technique specified at the end of this thread: [Highcharts tooltip overflow is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734746/highcharts-tooltip-overflow-is-hidden/10975843#10975843) to allow tooltips to flow outside the highcharts-container.

Everything is fine except when viewed in IE10 on Windows 8.

A large amount of white space is displayed underneath the chart when `.highcharts-container {overflow : visible}` is set.

Here's a demo of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4zG/6/

You need to view the demo in IE10 on Windows 8 to see it.

Is there another way to flow tooltips outside the container? Or a way to remove the mystery whitespace?

This is a problem for my app as it manifests in a very wide page with a horizontal scrollbar which in turn messes with some scrollTo js functions I have.

Comment: Managed to fix it by wrapping everything in a div with `overflow: hidden`

See fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4zG/8/

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by wrapping everything in a div with `overflow: hidden`

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="container" style="height: 300; width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.highcharts-container {overflow: visible !important; } 
.wrapper {overflow: hidden;} /* the fix! */
```

See fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4zG/8/