# Highcharts: How to make Tooltip position to be visible in the Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, tooltip

I am using a chart that is vertically longer that is wrapped inside a Container with Veritical scrolling enabled. Everything works fine. However, when I create a tooltip (in my case a big one), it gets hidden at times because it thinks the view port of chart is big. Is there any way to make the tooltip in a fixed position or always appear in the parent container's viewport ?

[image]

A sample fiddle having the similar problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Swsbb/52/

```
<div style='max-height:300px;overflow-y:auto'>
   <div id="container" style="height: 1000px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734746/highcharts-tooltip-overflow-is-hidden) question and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658043/highcharts-pie-tooltip-cuts-off).

Comment: @PawełFus: Both are different from what I've asked (see my fiddle). Thanks for sharing them though.

Comment: You can always disable built-in tooltip, and create your own, positioned outside that container. Simple use then [`plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver/mouseOut`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut) events.

Answer (score 1):

In tooltip there is option [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML), that adds advanced formatting to tooltip, also there is option [positioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner) - this is callback function that allows you change position for tooltip.

```
// fixed position
positioner: function () {
  return { x: 10, y: 10 };
},

// change position only for y
positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
  return { x: point.plotX, y: point.plotY - 50 };
}
```

- http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/tooltip
- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/positioner/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Swsbb/